# How to pass an element of an array to an other?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to take a new plate for a car and change the old one. I need the three letters to be capitals. The thing is that I cannot pass the "capital" element of newPlate array to the new_Plate array. The program compiles but the answer is soometimes %^&#%@$ and some other times nothing. I know I have a problem in the pointers.

```
void Car::set(char *newBrand, char *newPlate) 
{
    char new_Brand[80];
    char new_Plate[8];

    if(strlen(newPlate)==8)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   
            if(65<=(int)newPlate[i]<=90)
            {
                new_Plate[i]=newPlate[i]; // probably the problem
            }

            if(97<=(int)newPlate[i]<=122)
            {
                new_Plate[i]=(newPlate[i]+32); // probably the problem
            }

            cout<<new_Plate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 97 is ASCII for lowercase 'a'. You should probably be subtracting 32 instead of adding it.

Comment: Please don't use "magic" numbers such as `97` but just write `'a'`.

Comment: `65 <= (int)newPlate[i] <= 90` does not what you think it does.

Comment: `new_Plate[i]=(newPlate[i]+32);` => You don't want `new_Plate[i]=(newPlate[i]-32);` instead?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<3;i++) new_Plate[i] = std::toupper(newPlate[i]);` does what you want *and* is portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `new_Plate` string does not include a zero terminator.
Furthermore, `65<=(int)newPlate[i]<=90)` is not valid in C++. You should write something like

```
'A'<=newPlate[i] && newPlate[i]<='Z')
```

Comment: `65<=(int)newPlate[i]<=90` is indeed valid, but it doesn't mean what the OP thinks. Also it's rather ugly --> `65 <= (int) newPlate[i] <= 90`. GCC warns saying `warning: comparisons like ‘X<=Y<=Z’ do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]` but it does compile.

Comment: Your answer is almost good, but you should not claim that the expression is invalid try `if (3 < 5 < 2) fprintf(stdout, "WTF?\n");` The reason is, `(3 < 5)` evaluates to `1` and of course `1 < 2` thus it will print `WTF?`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the expression `65<=(int)newPlate[i]<=90` (*aside from being unreadable, use more white spaces to make it more readable*) is that it means `((65 <= (int) newPlate[i])) <= 90` which is not what it mathematically appears to mean.

This expression will ALWAYS be true because `65 <= (int) newPlate[i]` will evaluate to either `1` or `0` and it is of course always `< 90`.

Also, to make the code even more readable use `'A'` instead of `65` and the equivalent for any other character. Most programmers know that `'A'` is 65 in ascii but you make them stop one or two seconds to realize that you really mean `'A'`!

Also, you must terminate c-strings with a `'\0'` so you need one extra character at the end or, `cout << new_Plate` will invoke undefined behavior.

To print c strings the library will output characters from the input buffer until it finds the `'\0'`, since it's not present in your buffer there is no predictable way to print it.

Check this, do you understand the changes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Car {
public:
    Car();
    void set(const char *const newBrand, const char *const newPlate);
};

Car::Car() 
{
}


void
Car::set(const char *const newBrand, const char *const newPlate) 
{
    char new_Brand[80];
    char new_Plate[9];
    size_t length;
    size_t i;

    (void) new_Brand;
    length = strlen(newPlate);
    for (i = 0 ; ((i < length) && (i < sizeof(new_Plate) - 1)) ; ++i) {   
        if (('A' <= newPlate[i]) && (newPlate[i] <= 'Z')) {
            new_Plate[i] = newPlate[i];
        } else if (('a' <= newPlate[i]) && (newPlate[i] <= 'z')) {
            new_Plate[i] = (newPlate[i] - 32);
        }
    }
    new_Plate[i] = '\0';

    cout << '*' << new_Plate << '*' << endl;
}

int
main(void)
{
    Car car;    
    car.set("audi", "example text");
    return 0;
}
```